# What are possible errors of ip::tcp::socket.close()?

Tags: boost, boost-asio

Per the documentation:

> Note that, even if the function indicates an error, the underlying
>   descriptor is closed.

What are the possible errors?

Besides, if an error occurs in `socket.close()`, will the result of `socket.is_open()` always be `false` in spite of any error in `socket.close()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when Boost.Asio depends on the OS implementation, then it will neither specify the conditions under which errors may occur nor the error codes that may be returned.

If error handling depends on the exact error code, then one can use the [BSD API mapping documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/bsd_sockets.html) or [consult the implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.58.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp#L316-L320) to determine which OS calls are being made.
In the case of [`basic_socket::close()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/close/overload2.html), the implementation will use either [`close()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/close.html) or [`closesocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx).  One can use the appropriate OS documentation to determine the error cases, as well as the error return values that are associated with Boost.Asio error codes located in [`asio/error.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.58.0/include/boost/asio/error.hpp).

As noted in `basic_socket::close()` documentation, the underlying descriptor will be closed regardless of an error.  Furthermore, the [SocketService](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SocketService.html) Type Requirements mandates that a post-condition of `close()` is that  `is_open()` returns false.

> `service.close(impl, ec);` → `!service.is_open(impl)`

Also, while the Boost.Asio documentation is the most appropriate place to look for the specified behavior, the dated (2007-03-11) [Networking Library Proposal for TR2 (Revision 1)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2175.pdf) based on Asio occasionally contains some helpful wording to understanding details:

> `error_code close(implementation_type& impl, error_code& ec);`
>
> ... establishes the postcondition as if by POSIX `close()`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the documentation, but it makes sense if the socket has a protocol to explicitly shut down communication (think SSL).

If the shutdown sequence cannot be completed (because the endpoint is down/unreachable?) then that's an error, but the socket is still closed (so this side doesn't suffer a resource leak because of uncontrollable external factors)

**Note**

> *Remarks*
>
> For portable behaviour with respect to graceful closure of a connected socket, call `shutdown()` before closing the socket.

[from the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/close/overload2.html)